# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python, linux

```
save = "/root/foo/"
PERF_PATH="/root/foobar/"
```

So, Initially I had the variable `save` and `perf_path` in the `cmd`. but now, I want to substitute it for enhanced readability.

I wanted to create a folder into which the variable `app[a]` will eventually get stored.

```
direc = os.mkdir(save + i + "-"+ j +"-" + k + "-" +l)
```

Creating a directory does not seem to a problem. 
but joining a non-string value variable to a string seems to be a problem.

```
cmd = "taskset -c %s" + PERF_PATH + "perf2 stat -t %s e r4008387e1 -f -o" +save + direc + "%s.csv &" % (cpus_list[a],fpid[a],apps[a])
pro= subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`

```
cmd = "taskset -c %s" + str(PERF_PATH) + "perf2 stat -t %s e r4008387e1 -f -o" +str(save) + str(direc) + "%s.csv &" % (cpus_list[a],fpid[a],apps[a])
```

that wasn't of much help either.

any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: The error message is telling you that one of the variables you're trying to add is `None`. Figure out which one it is.

Comment: But then once you get past that error, you're going to get a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. The problem there is that `%` has higher precedence than `+`, but the _real_ problem is that you're trying to mix string concatenation and `%` formatting together at the same time, which is hard to get right, and even harder to read even if you do get it right. Just do one or the other—ideally `%` formatting, or, even better, `{}` formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.mkdir()` does not return anything, so `direc` is set to None.

Do this instead:

```
direc = save + i + "-"+ j +"-" + k + "-" +l
os.mkdir(direc)
```

You really want to use `os.path.join()` and string formatting to build paths though, it'll be a lot easier to read:

```
save = "/root/foo"
PERF_PATH="/root/foobar"

direc = os.path.join(save, '-'.join((i, j, k, l)))
os.mkdir(direc)
```

For `subprocess.Popen()`, pass in a list instead of a string for the command and arguments, and leave `shell` to the default value of `False`, there is no need to have the shell handle that:

```
cmd = ['taskset', 
    '-c', cpus_list[a], PERF_PATH, 'perf2', 'stat',
    '-t', fpid[a], 'e', 'r4008387e1',
    '-f', '-o', save, 
    os.path.join(direc, "%s.csv" % apps[a])
]

pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

Comment: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

it still has this problem. that's something I dont seem to understand. Everything is a string variable

Comment: It took me minute to understand my mistake!.

Comment: The module `os.join` is not there.. I think were trying to say `os.path.join`

Comment: It does not seem to work. I am still trying to figure out what the issue is..
I tried. `os.system(str(cmd))`
`sh: [taskset,: command not found`
that's the error I get.

Comment: @user2015933: No, don't use `os.system()`, stick with `subprocess`. `str(cmd)` will give a string starting with `['taskset', ...]`, not a shell-compatible command.

Comment: `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings` - this is teh error I get with what you said.. seems to be an encoding issue.

Comment: Is `cpus_list[a]` a string or something else? If not, use `str(cpus_list[a])` instead. Same for the other items in the list.

Comment: it was because of the datetime object that I added!. I did not convert that into a string

Answer (score 0):

os.mkdir returns None.

Trying to add a string to a None is a no no. If you want to build up a string out of different types try using format:

```
s = 'hi there number {no}'.format(no=81)
```

This way is much more readable, thus debuggable, anyway